# Solving an inequality graphically

Tags: inequality, graphing-functions

> $$\frac{2x - 5}6 < \frac{x^2 - 1}4 - \frac{x(x+1)}3$$

Should I solve it by turning it firstly into an equation of the form $ax^2+bx+c>0$ and then draw the graph or draw the graph of $\displaystyle y = \frac{2x - 5}6$ and in the same figure the one of $\displaystyle y=\frac{x^2 - 1}4 - \frac{x(x+1)}3$ and then watch where the equation is right?

Comment: Either approach works, perhaps the second is more direct.

Comment: yes you can do that! simplifying the equation on the right would give you an parabolic equation! and so you would be comparing a parabola with the line of equation = (2x-5)/6

Answer (score 1):

You can do either way. I think the first one is simpler.
Rewriting we have
$$4x - 10 < 3(x^2 - 1) - 4x(x + 1) \implies x^2 + 8x - 7 < 0 \implies (x + 4)^2 - 23 < 0$$

It's very easy to draw that parabola: you first draw $x^2$, then apply the two translations $x \mapsto x + 4$ and $y \mapsto y + 23$ and you are done.

Comment: When I multiply by $12$, I obtain $4x - 10 < 3(x^2 - 1) - 4x(x + 1)$.

Comment: Which gives $4x-10<3x^2-4x^2-3-4\implies 4x-10<-x^2-7$.

Comment: Further implying $x^2+4x-3<0$.

Comment: @N.F.Taussig Argh, the hurry, thanks!

Comment: @MickG  If you expand, you should obtain $4x - 10 < 3x^2 - 3 - 4x^2 - 4\color{red}{x}$.

Comment: Whoops, I lost an $x$ :). So the result was correct.